# CSS not drawing border below active thumbnail in MVC 5 View For image-gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

The below CSS is supposed to cause a white border to appear below the currently active thumbnail in an image gallery but it does not.

```
.carousel-thumbnails .carousel-indicators li {
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        border: none;
        box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);

        &.active {
            border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
        }
    }
```

Visual Studio 17 underlines the "&" symbol says there is a missing property. I've seen examples of setting things active like P or H1 but I don't understand why there is the "&" symbol there. The CSS came from the following link which has the complete set of code.

[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/peterbenoit/pen/rYjqJB)

I've added the sample gallery to my ASP.NET MVC 5 application in a view. It all works except this CSS part to draw a thin border below the active thumbnail. Can someone please tell me how to fix it or is this something that just does not work under Visual Studio 2017?

Below is a copy of the MVC View I've created using the sample:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Claremont Botanical Garden";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<br />
<link href="~/Content/slideshow/carousel-with-thumbails.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/slideshow/carousel-with-thumbails.js"></script>

<!--Carousel Wrapper-->
<div id="carousel-thumb" class="carousel slide carousel-fade carousel-thumbnails" data-ride="carousel">
    <!--Slides-->

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100"
                 src="~/Content/Images/Photos/Animals/_Squirrel-01-DSC_0028-1440.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100"
                 src="~/Content/Images/Photos/Animals/_Squirrel-02-DSC_0131-1440.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100"
                 src="~/Content/Images/Photos/Animals/_Squirrel-03-DSC_0154-1440.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100"
                 src="~/Content/Images/Photos/Animals/_Bird-01-DSC_0639-1440.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100"
                 src="~/Content/Images/Photos/Animals/_bird-02-DSC_0158-1440.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100"
                 src="~/Content/Images/Photos/Animals/_Bird-03-DSC_0606-1440.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100"
                 src="~/Content/Images/Photos/Animals/_Bird-04-DSC_0637-1410.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100"
                 src="~/Content/Images/Photos/Animals/_Bird-hawk-01-DSC_0550-1440.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>




    </div>
    <!--/.Slides-->
    <!--Controls-->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-thumb" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-thumb" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    <!--/.Controls-->

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="0">
            <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid"
                 src="~/Content/Images/Photos/Animals/_Squirrel-01-DSC_0028-1440.jpg">
        </li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="1">
            <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid"
                 src="~/Content/Images/Photos/Animals/_Squirrel-02-DSC_0131-1440.jpg">
        </li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="2">
            <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid"
                 src="~/Content/Images/Photos/Animals/_Squirrel-03-DSC_0154-1440.jpg">
        </li>

        <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="3" class="active">
            <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid"
                 src="~/Content/Images/Photos/Animals/_Bird-01-DSC_0639-1440.jpg">
        </li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="4">
            <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid"
                 src="~/Content/Images/Photos/Animals/_bird-02-DSC_0158-1440.jpg">
        </li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="5">
            <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid"
                 src="~/Content/Images/Photos/Animals/_Bird-03-DSC_0606-1440.jpg">
        </li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="6">
            <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid"
                 src="~/Content/Images/Photos/Animals/_Bird-04-DSC_0637-1410.jpg">
        </li>

        <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="7">
            <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid"
                 src="~/Content/Images/Photos/Animals/_Bird-hawk-01-DSC_0550-1440.jpg">
        </li>

    </ol>
</div>
<!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you copied is [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/guide), not plain CSS. If you aren't using a pre-processor, the code as you copied it will not work.

The ampersand `&` in this context means the selector `.carousel-thumbnails .carousel-indicators li.active` [The Sass Ampersand](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/).

So if you aren't using a preprocessor, remove the nested rule `&.active {  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff; }` and instead, create a new (non-nested) rule `.carousel-thumbnails .carousel-indicators li.active { border-bottom: 4px solid #fff; }` and it should work (I'm assuming you have something else applying the `.active` class when the element is active).

Comment: Thank you Adam! Your recommendation worked. I had not heard of SCSS or its ampersand functionality. Another case of there is always something new to learn. The active thumbnails are now getting the highlighted bar below them.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the CSS code.
You used with spaces between the classes names inplace of use with commas.

Your correct code should be like that:

```
    .carousel-thumbnails ,.carousel-indicators ,li {
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        border: none;
        box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        &.active

    {
        border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    }
    }
```

good luck!